# Parse JSON via WebRequest

Tags: c#, json

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url" + result + "url");
string json;
var response = request.GetResponse();
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

using (var streamr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = streamr.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(json);
}
```

I have this code that gets me the following sample string

```
[{"Type":1,"Country":"CA","Channel":"","Code":"1EZ","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2015-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":2,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"UAD","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":2,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"TPQ","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":3,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"SVC_PRIORITY","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"}]
```

But I want to only get the Start & End Values - Is there a JSON interpreter that can do this?

Comment: There are plenty of them. The most common seems to be JSON.net http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. Also available via nuget

Comment: sweet, what would be the best way with json.net to parse my string? Serialize, Deserialize, Linq? I'll read up about it more but if you know it I may aswell ask

Comment: If you look at the examples given on the site, it should be quite clear, you need to deserialize a string to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something to get you started. Deserialize your json to a class using JSON.NET:

```
var jsonStr = "[{\"Type\":1,\"Country\":\"CA\",\"Channel\":\"\",\"Code\":\"1EZ\",\"Start\":\"2014 - 10 - 24T00: 00:00\",\"End\":\"2015 - 10 - 23T00: 00:00\"},{\"Type\":2,\"Country\":\"\",\"Channel\":\"\",\"Code\":\"UAD\",\"Start\":\"2014 - 10 - 24T00: 00:00\",\"End\":\"2017 - 10 - 23T00: 00:00\"},{\"Type\":2,\"Country\":\"\",\"Channel\":\"\",\"Code\":\"TPQ\",\"Start\":\"2014 - 10 - 24T00: 00:00\",\"End\":\"2017 - 10 - 23T00: 00:00\"},{\"Type\":3,\"Country\":\"\",\"Channel\":\"\",\"Code\":\"SVC_PRIORITY\",\"Start\":\"2014 - 10 - 24T00: 00:00\",\"End\":\"2017 - 10 - 23T00: 00:00\"}]";
var myObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List< MyObject>>(jsonStr);
```

And your class example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: from this point how do I get Start & End values? DateTime start = MyObject.Start? -- doesnt work :s

Comment: You can parse the dates using: var date = DateTime.Parse(MyObject.Start); Which will parse your string dates to c# datetime object.

Comment: I am getting an error 'An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property Form1.MyObject.Start' preventing me from doing this. I have my code in public Form1() and MyObject class outside of it

Comment: You are trying to access your class property in a static way and it is not static. You need a concrete implementation of the class to be able to access it. e.g. var myobject = new MyObject { Start = "21-03-2016" }; var date = DateTime.Parse(myobject.Start);

Comment: Hmm... but I do not want a static value? I have multiple URL's I want to loop through with similar but different Start and End Dates. II want to display the Start & End values from the url so they cant have the same values. Im a little new to programming so sorry if I am not catching onto something I should be.

Comment: Create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

With http://json2csharp.com/ generate class from json:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```

Then add [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from Nuget.

And deserialize json to generated object:

```
List<RootObject> o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

And get interesting properties.

Comment: This will only do a single object. Most likely will require a list.